# Wordpress update data from api

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin to create posts with data from an API. I have to check the state of the data on the api every time, if there is a change, it will update the posts and acf fields. I have a post title check so as not to duplicate posts. But how can I check posts correctly so that I can update acf fields every time if there is new data and not duplicate posts?

```
    if( isset( $_POST['enable'] ) ) {

        // JOB API
        $url='https://api.com/test/';
        $result     = file_get_contents( $url );
        $result_data = json_decode( $result );


        foreach ($result_data as  $job) {

            $ref_code = $job->RefCode;
            $post_title = $job->JobTitle;
            $post_exists = post_exists( $post_title );
            $job_id = $job->JobId;
            $job_date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($job->Published));
            
            if (!get_page_by_title($post_title, 'OBJECT', 'jobs') ) {

                $data = array(
                    'post_type'   => 'jobs',
                    'post_title'  => $post_title,
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'post_date' => $job_date,
                    'post_date_gmt' => $job_date
                );

                $post_id = wp_insert_post( $data );
                wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'regulare-job', 'jobscat', 'post_tag' );     

                // Job DATA API
                $job_api_url ='https://api.com/test/' . $ref_code;
                $job_api_result = file_get_contents( $job_api_url );
                $result_data = json_decode( $job_api_result );

                //Update ACF fields
                update_field( 'location', $job->RegionCity, $post_id );
                update_field( 'job_intro', $result_data->Intro, $post_id );
                update_field( 'job_offer', $result_data->data[0]->Text, $post_id );
                update_field( 'job_requirement', $result_data->data[1]->Text, $post_id );
                update_field( 'text_c2', $result_data->data[2]->Text, $post_id );
                update_field( 'single_job_ref_code', $result_data->RefCode, $post_id );
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I customized your code with some parts how i achieved it for myself.
It might need some customization. (See comments within code for additional info)

What I do:

1.) check if post is already existing based on your title (and get its id)

2.) if it is already existing => update data (ACF-Fields)

3.) if it is not existing => create new post and update meta data (ACF-Fields)

To fill the acf-fields I use a custom function based on ACF-Field-Keys.

You can also create a custom cron job to run this function every (minute, hour...)

```
function api_fetcher_function(){

if( isset( $_POST['enable'] ) ) {

    // JOB API
    $url='https://api.com/test/';
    $result     = file_get_contents( $url );
    $result_data = json_decode( $result );


    foreach ($result_data as  $job) {

        $ref_code = $job->RefCode;
        $post_title = sanitize_title($job->JobTitle);

        /* check if CPT-Post with given slug already exists */
        $existing_post = get_page_by_path($post_title,'OBJECT', 'jobs');

        $job_id = $job->JobId;
        $job_date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($job->Published));
        
        /* if post doesnt exist create a new one */
        if($existing_post === null){ 

             $inserted_post = wp_insert_post([
               'post_name' => $post_title, 
               'post_title' => $post_title, 
               'post_type' => 'jobs',
               'post_status' => 'publish',
               'post_date' => $job_date,
               'post_date_gmt' => $job_date
            ]);
            /* continue after successful insert (single item) */
            /* special error handling can be placed within if */

            if( is_wp_error($inserted_post)){
               continue;
            }
    
            /* Update Meta Info of new post */
            updateJobsMeta($job, $inserted_post);

         }else{

            $existing_job_id = $existing_post->ID;

            /*you can add some additional check if you have some timestamps within your api and ACF */


            /*$existing_jobs_timestamp might not be needed => based on your available data*/
            $existing_jobs_timestamp = get_field('updated_at', $existing_job_id);
            
            /*if you have some timestamps to use*/
            if($job->Published >= $existing_jobs_timestamp){
              updateJobsMeta($job ,$existing_job_id);
            } 
            /*if you dont have some timestamps to use just remove the if around the update function and the $existing_jobs_timestamp*/
            
         }
    }

}
}

function updateJobsMeta($job ,$id){
    $ref_code = $job->RefCode;
    $job_api_url ='https://api.com/test/' . $ref_code;
    $job_api_result = file_get_contents( $job_api_url );
    $result_data = json_decode( $job_api_result );

    /* Update Fillable list based on your needs => keys can be found within your acf group in wp-backend (might be hidden by default) */
    $fillable = [
        'field_5f312082435dd' => $job->JobId,
        'field_5f312095435de' => $job->JobTitle,
        'acf_field_key....' => $job->Published
        ...
    ];

    /* updates fields based on acf-key */
    foreach($fillable as $key => $name){
        update_field( $key, $name, $id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I cannot understand this part  `get_field('updated_at', $existing_job_id);`  I need add date to acf field by updated_at key when i create new post and check with date when i want any updates ?

Comment: My code is based on a hourly cron-job and I only update my data if the timestamp of the already saved post is different to the timestamp from the api. With the use of the timestamp I dont have to compare every single field if there is any change. If you remove the timestamp comparison you will update the data even if there is no change.

Comment: Where did you get this data from?  `get_field('updated_at', $existing_job_id);`

Comment: Within my fillable array I have a acf-field-key for the "updated_at" field. As mentioned in the comments the acf-field-keys are hidden by default. You have to use the right one. (the keys field_5f31 .... are my personal keys. => must be changed to your key)

Comment: That is, I must first add the date from the api to these fields and then compare. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: In my usecase the api provided an updated_at field. I´m not sure if your api changes the $job->Published timestamp. If not just remove the timestamp check and update the fields every single time.

Comment: I used this source to build up my API-Fetcher: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWM41Rcao3s&t . Hope this might help out to understand it a bit better.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will check

Comment: Thanks for video tutorial and code, after watching video i fixed my code.